# Android: where is the onUnTouchEvent of Activity?

Tags: android, events, touch

Am I missing something?

There is this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
```

I use it on `Activity`. It does fire on "touch" events but NOT on a potential "untouch" event (releasing the finger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sorry, I should have search further...*

It does the trick: [How to get a continuous Touch Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539524/how-to-get-a-continuous-touch-event/2539739#2539739)

More exact, in my case:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
  // here we have the "untouch" event
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [ACTION_UP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP)?

Comment: Yes ;) Now I saw it, see my answer.